# Trying to understand Big Mart Sales Prediction project

Tags: data-science

I am new to data science. I was referring to [this site](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/bigmart-sales-solution-top-20/) for Big Mart Sales Prediction project. In data exploration part, I am not able to understand following syntax :

```
categorical_columns = [x for x in data.dtypes.index if data.dtypes[x]=='object']
categorical_columns = [x for x in categorical_columns if x not in ['Item_Identifier','Outlet_Identifier','source']]

for col in categorical_columns:
    print '\nFrequency of Categories for varible %s'%col
    print data[col].value_counts()
```

And in step 2 of feature engineering I cannot understand following syntax:

`miss_bool = (data['Item_Visibility'] == 0)`

I am new to stackoverflow. If any issue regarding question please do mention.

Comment: It just iterates across all the columns data type to check which one is an object, then it excludes some of them (Item_identifier...), then it prints the count of all of them. Finally, it creates a boolean (it will be Pandas Series) which is true if Item_Visibility is equal to 0.